Datatables JS br tag doesn't work in pdf file
I'm using DataTables 2.0.6 to list and export data. I am using a customise function to export files.
Everything is OK but there is br tags inside the header and cells of table (between th or td). When I click PDF button the file is coming but where there are br tags, long spaces appear instead of going to the bottom line.
Also, when I look at the codes in Chrome console, it looks like the picture below.
table header cell - th
The exported pdf file looks like below.
pdf file
My html codes:
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered border-bottom" style="width:100%"
       id="arac-datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Plaka) <br />
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SaseNo)
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Marka - Model<br />
                Model Yılı
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Müşteri
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Durumu
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Şube-<br />
                Kaydı Yapan-<br />
                Kayıt Tarihi
            </th>
            
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            ...my cells...
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

My js codes:
$('#arac-datatable').DataTable({

        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        fixedHeader: true,
        paging: true,
        pageLength: 50,
        order: [[0, 'desc']],
        ordering: true,
        buttons: {
            dom: {
                button: {
                    tag: 'button',
                    className: ''
                }
            },
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                className: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning',
                titleAttr: 'PDF Olarak İndir',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF',
                filename: 'pdf-export',
                extension: '.pdf',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    search: 'applied',
                    order: 'applied'
                },
                customize: function (doc) {
                    doc.content.splice(0, 1);
                    doc.pageMargins = [40, 80, 40, 40];
                    doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 10;
                    doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 10;
                    
                    doc.content[0].table.widths = ['20%', '30%', '30%', '20%'];

                    doc.styles.tableHeader = {
                        color: 'navy',
                        alignment: 'center'
                    };

                    doc['header'] = (function () {
                        return {
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    image: logo
                                },
                                {
                                    alignment: 'center',
                                    italics: true,
                                    text: dtableheaderorta,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    margin: [10, 0],
                                    width:400
                                },
                                {
                                    alignment: 'right',
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    text: dtableheadersag
                                }
                            ],
                            margin: 30
                        }
                    }); 

                    doc['footer'] = (function (page, pages) {
                        return {
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    alignment: 'left',
                                    text: dtablefootersol
                                },
                                {
                                    alignment: 'right',
                                    text: ['Sayfa ', { text: page.toString() }, ' / ', { text: pages.toString() }]
                                }
                            ],
                            margin: [30, 0]
                        }
                    });

                    for (var x = 2; x < doc.content[0].table.body.length; x+=2) {
                        doc.content[0].table.body[x].forEach(function (h) {
                            h.fillColor = dtableRowEvenBg;
                            
                        });
                    }

                    var objLayout = {};
                    objLayout['width'] = function (i) { return 800; };
                    objLayout['hLineWidth'] = function (i) { return .5; };
                    objLayout['vLineWidth'] = function (i) { return .5; };
                    objLayout['hLineColor'] = function (i) { return '#aaa'; };
                    objLayout['vLineColor'] = function (i) { return '#aaa'; };
                    objLayout['paddingLeft'] = function (i) { return 4; };
                    objLayout['paddingRight'] = function (i) { return 4; };
                    doc.content[0].layout = objLayout;
                }
            },

            {
                extend: 'excel',
                className: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
                titleAttr: 'Excel Tablosu İndir',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> EXCEL',
                filename: 'excel-export',
                extension: '.xlsx',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    search: 'applied',
                    order: 'applied'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                className: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
                titleAttr: 'Excel CSV Formatı.',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> CSV',
                filename: 'csv-excel-export',
                extension: '.csv',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    search: 'applied',
                    order: 'applied'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                className: 'btn btn-sm btn-light',
                titleAttr: 'Tabloyu Kopyala',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-copy"></i> Kopyala',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    search: 'applied',
                    order: 'applied',
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                className: 'btn btn-sm btn-dark',
                titleAttr: 'Tabloyu Yazdır',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Yazdır',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    search: 'applied',
                    order: 'applied',
                }
            }]
        },
        
        language: {
            url: dtableLangUrl
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                target: 0,
                visible: false,
                searchable: false
            }
        ]
    });

I tried lots of things. For example:
var rowsss = doc.content[0].table.body;
                    for (i = 0; i < rowsss.length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < rowsss[i].length; j++) {
                            rowsss[i][j].text = rowsss[i][j].text.replace('a', 'x');
                            rowsss[i][j].text = rowsss[i][j].text.replace('\t', 'x');
                            rowsss[i][j].text = rowsss[i][j].text.replace('\r', 'x');
                            rowsss[i][j].text = rowsss[i][j].text.replace('<br/>', 'x');
                            rowsss[i][j].text = rowsss[i][j].text.replace('<br>', 'x');
                            rowsss[i][j].text = rowsss[i][j].text.replace('<br />', 'x');
                        }
                    }

This method is working and changes 'a' to 'x' but it doesnt work for whitespaces.

By default, HTML tags embedded in cell text are removed. That is why you are only left with a series of whitespaces in the relevant PDF cells. You can use the approach shown in this answer to convert your HTML<br /> tag (and the surrounding spaces) into a PDF newline. The specifics in the linked answer are for converting an HTML <a> into a PDF link - but you can adapt that general approach for your specific situation.

Thank you but it didnt solve my problem. I edited the last part of my question. I only tried a similar way. I can change other characters but I cant change whitespace.

Based on the approach in the linked answer, the following works for me: cell.text = cell.text.replace(/\s{2,}/, '\r');. This is used inside the row.forEach(function( cell ) {...} loop. It's the only statement needed in that loop. The regular expression /\s{2,}/ matches two or more whitespace characters, and replaces them with a newline character.

If you want to, you can answer your own question, showing (and explaining) what your specific solution is.
